# Magento 2 REST API: What's the difference between carts and guest-carts?

Tags: magento2, cart, rest-api

Our team is developing a store using Magento 2 as the backend, with a decoupled client-side layer using Node.js/Express/React/Redux. So obviously we are relying heavily on the REST API, which is far from being well documented.

I am now developing the cart operations, and I noticed there are different endpoints for carts:

- `/V1/carts/`
- `/V1/guest-carts/`

Which is strange, because:

- the cart objects that they provide as responses are identical
- their responses have a `customer` key (why would `guest-carts` have this?)
- their responses have a `customer_is_guest` key (why would both have this, since the endpoints already provide this distinction?)

Anyway, how should I deal with both endpoints? Should I necessarily use both, since most of the logic is handled by ourselves in the frontend/middlewares?